# Difference between let tableView = UITableView() and let tableView: UITableView! these two statements

Tags: initialization, tableview, declaration

I am new in iOS Development, what is major difference in these two statements and what logic is behind them. when which statement we should use...

Answer (score 0):

```
let tableView = UITableView()
```

You are creating an instance of UITableView and assigning it to the constants named tableView.

```
let tableView: UITableView!
```

You are telling the compiler that tableView constant will contain an instance of UITableView in the future and with `!` you are making sure that this constant will have a value before accessing it. But as you have declared it as a constant so you cannot assign/change the value to it. Use `var` to make it variable (assuming you know the difference between `let` and `var`).

For better understanding go through the [Swift Basics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html).

Comment: now i understand, which is better approach in which scenario and what happened behind them, if you have knowledge about it, explain me little bit. Thanks

Comment: @UmerKhan I would recommend you to go through the basics (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html).